# How to relabel column values

Tags: r

This seems like a simple task but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I have a dataframe column with the following structure:

`df = as.data.frame(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4))`

I also have the following vectors:

```
index = seq(1,2)
labels = c('Control','Treatment')
```

The index is updated by a for loop and all I want to do is replace all of the values in the df column that match the index with the appropriate label (eg all values of 1 and 2 in the df will be replaced with 'Control'). So far the closest I've gotten is:

```
df$col[df$col == index[1]] = labels[1]
```

If `index[1]` is replaced with `index`, only the first value of the vector is matched. How can I do this such that all values are matched and replaced?

Thank you!

Comment: what have you tried so far? does a `join` followed by a `coalesce` serve your purpose??

Comment: Where is `df$col`? Try ``df$`c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)`[df$`c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)` == index[1]] = labels[1]`` or `df[, 1][df[, 1] == index[1]] = labels[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you want to do. But from your description, I suppose that what you might need is a `factor`:

```
df <- data.frame(col=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4))
labs <- c("first", "second", "third", "fourth")
df$col2 <- factor(df$col, labels=labs)
df
#   col   col2
# 1   1  first
# 2   1  first
# 3   2 second
# 4   2 second
# 5   3  third
# 6   3  third
# 7   4 fourth
# 8   4 fourth
```

You can change these labels by `levels`, for example:

```
> levels(df$col2)[3:4] <- c("tre", "fyra")
> df
  col   col2
1   1  first
2   1  first
3   2 second
4   2 second
5   3    tre
6   3    tre
7   4   fyra
8   4   fyra
```

Comment: Holy s***. That looks way easier than what I ended up doing. Let me give that a shot and see how it works. I figured this should be a relatively simple operation. Thanks!